# Working with Joomla: Useful Tools for Developers and Users

Tags: discussion

How about creating a wiki post, where we can list handful tools/applications we are using, when working/developing with Joomla, that make our life easier ?

From desktop apps, VM software, to php scripts or online services. 
We could categorize e.g. Database Tools, VMs, etc.
Each tool can have a quick description and a link for more info and eventually we can expand it, update it with new stuff etc.

It's under discussion if we would allow posts about commercial products, or the list should be limited to only Free / open source stuff.

I believe that the whole community and especially new users will benefit from a such a list, and we can use it as reference in many of our answers.

What's your feedback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Love the idea.

[What tools can I use to help assist me with Joomla development?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/12143/what-tools-can-i-use-to-help-assist-me-with-joomla-development/12144#12144)

Even for me, it would be interesting to see what other tools people use

Comment: I also really love this idea... and already see the question in JSE being an awesome resource.

Comment: Nice work guys. Already found one useful tool for me, despite I have been developing for long time. Added some new ones and will add more tomorrow. Keep up the good work!

Comment: @FFrewin - May I also suggest that if any commercial tools are added, then we must specify that it's commercial. Hopefully all tools added will be free but just incase :)

Comment: Love the Idea. Really a great approach :)